# C on Raspberry Pi: SPI order changes when 'printf' statement is executed

Tags: c, raspberry-pi2, spi

I am working on a project in C on the raspberry pi 2 in which the pi is polling a microcontroller via SPI when the microcontroller asserts a particular pin.

There are two functions that are intended to be executed in this fashion.  One of the functions - LNK_pollNetwork() - checks to see if the request pin is high and - if it is - then it downloads the data until the pin is low again, then parses.  The other function - LNK_generateNetStat() - sends a byte requesting the network status and then downloads data until the pin is low again.

It seems that if I place a 'printf' statement just after the poll byte in LNK_generateNetStat(), everything works fine.  If I remove the printf statement, then the program goes haywire and it is clear to me that the other function is executing almost in parallel with this function.

Both functions are on the same thread... or so I believe.

```
void LNK_generateNetStat(){
    uint8_t statusSerialString[(NETSTAT_HEADER_BYTES
                    + (MAX_NUM_OF_NODES
                    * NETSTAT_FIELD_WIDTH_BYTES))];
    uint8_t i = 0;

    SPI_transfer(0x86);

    /* if this printf is executed, all works normally */
    if(verbose)
        printf("Network status polled");

    while(bcm2835_gpio_lev(REQ_PIN) == HIGH){
        statusSerialString[i] = SPI_transfer(0xfe);
        i++;
    }

    /* parsing code below this line */
    /* ... */
}
```

The other function simply polls the request pin and, if it is high, then starts pulling data until the pin is low:

```
void LNK_pollNetwork(){
    if(bcm2835_gpio_lev(REQ_PIN) == HIGH){
        int i = 0;
        uint8_t payload[PAYLOAD_MAX_LENGTH];

        SPI_transfer(0xff);  // dummy read - allows slave to load the buffer
        while(bcm2835_gpio_lev(REQ_PIN) == HIGH){
            payload[i] = SPI_transfer(0xff);
            i++;
        }

        /* payload parsing below this line */
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Both of these should be executed sequentially.  There is a higher level task manager that executes LNK_pollNetwork() every 1ms and LNK_generateNetStat() every 1250ms.

I know that LNK_generateNetStat() is being pre-empted because I have used different values in the SPI polling routine for each function in order to identify what is going on.  The 0x86 executes normally and should begin polling with bytes numbered 0xfe, but I am seeing 0xff bytes in many cases and - sometimes - they are intermixed.  I'm using a logic analyzer to observe.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is your `SPI_transfer` waiting for the transfer to complete? Otherwise it's just that your `printf` is giving it some time to complete...

Comment: What are the values of PAYLOAD_MAX_LENGTH, NETSTAT_HEADER_BYTES, MAX_NUM_OF_NODES, NETSTAT_FIELD_WIDTH_BYTES

Comment: @EugeneSh - Yes, the microcontroller is an MSP430 acting as a slave, so it isn't nearly as fast as the Pi.  It asserts a 'wait' for each SPI transfer until it processes that byte (it only has a 1 byte buffer) and can respond with the next byte appropriately.  In most cases, a complete byte is transferred in 28.6uS and the wait increases that time by 18.5us.

Comment: @nsilent22 PAYLOAD_MAX_LENGTH - 959, NETSTAT_HEADER_BYTES - 9, MAX_NUM_OF_NODES - 16, NETSTAT_FIELD_WIDTH_BYTES - 5

Comment: please place information in the question itself rather than into comments.

Comment: the question+the code snippets strongly indicate a `race` condition.  strongly suggest: do not interrupt one communication sequence to while another communication sequence is in progreas